# Conditional Layout Blocks in CMS Page depending if logged in

Tags: layout, login, frontend, cms-block

I would like to add login block only if customer are not logged in.
So in my cms.xml page i change this code

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml"/>
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
            <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
            <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

this is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links">
            <!--
                The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
            -->
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_company</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links_sm" after="footer_links2">
            <!--
                The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
            -->
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_sm</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>

<cms_menu>
    <reference name="left_first">
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_menu" >
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cms_menu</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_menu>

<cms_page translate="label">
    <label>CMS Pages (All)</label>
    <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>

    <update handle="cms_menu"/>

   <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml"/>
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
        <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml"/>
        <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
    </block>
</reference>
    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="content">
                <remove  name="customer_form_login" />
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>



</cms_page>

<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <label>CMS Home Page</label>
</cms_index_index>

<cms_index_defaultindex>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="default_home_page" template="cms/default/home.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_defaultindex>

<cms_index_noroute translate="label">
    <label>CMS No-Route Page</label>
</cms_index_noroute>

<cms_index_defaultnoroute>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="default_no_route" template="cms/default/no-route.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_defaultnoroute>
```

In my logic this means that if the customer is logged in the login form will be removed but actually it will remove in every case.
What is wrong?

Comment: when your checking the code are you logged in?? The code seems to look fine.

Comment: can you post your entire xml file?

Comment: I post my entire xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your xml code is invalid, you added your `customer_logged_in` inside your `cms_page` reference

It should be outside of `cms_page` try like below:

```
<cms_page translate="label">
    <label>CMS Pages (All)</label>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml"/>
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
            <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml"/>
            <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_page>


<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="content">
        <remove  name="customer_form_login" />
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

Or you can find `customer_logged_in` in `customer.xml` layout file and add remove block code in that file.

Comment: Both methods you have suggested are working fine!! Thank you very much!!